# Telegraf - query output from running process

Tags: python, influxdb, telegraf

I need some advice

I am trying to setup a Telegraf service which reads sensor data from a python script and outputs it to influxDB.

The python script basically is:

```
import time
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    data = get_sensor_data()
    print(influxdb_formatted(data))
```

The Telegraf config file has an exec input module defined:

```
[[inputs.exec]]
    commands = [
        "python3 sensor_data.py"
    ]
    timeout = "5s"
    data_format = "influx"
```

Telegraf runs the python script at specified frequency, the script outputs the sensor data in InfluxDB format to STDOUT, gets picked up by Telegraf which outputs it to InfluxDB.

The problem is that the sensors need a 'warm-up' period before values are stable. It be better if the python script was continually running and Telegraf could 'query' the values periodically.

What is a good solution to this problem?

Comment: You should push data directly into influxdb from python. https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python

There's no other way to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd solve this is by having the Python executable write its output to a file, and have telegraf scrape the file using the [file input plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/file).

Alternatively, you can use the [execd input plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/file) to run the python executable and collect its output.